# You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity on using Recycle view with Glide

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-glide

I"m using adapter to load images and text inside my fragment which is attached to Activity A. But when I close app and open the app then app crashes with error

```
You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed)
```

But 2nd time when I open app, then it runs smoothly.

But  if again I close app and reopen then app crashes with same error and Once error occurs and on second time it runs smoothly.

Here is my adapter classs. Home is my Fragment

```html
public class TopAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TopAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<location> bookslist;
    CardView cv;
    FirebaseAuth fauth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference dbreference;
    location g;
    private Home context;





    public TopAdapter(Home context, ArrayList<location> bookslist){
        this.bookslist = bookslist;
        this.context = context; // add this as a field in your adapter class.
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_top,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);

    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView teacher_name,teacher_location;
        LinearLayout profile_details;
        ImageView iv;




        MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_card_view);
            iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.placePic);
            teacher_name= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_name);
            teacher_location = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_location);
            profile_details = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_details);

            fauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        g = bookslist.get(position);

        holder.teacher_location.setText(g.getBlocas());
        holder.teacher_name.setText(g.getSellername());

        holder.profile_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                g = bookslist.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), gender_details.class);
                

                intent.putExtra(MOBILE, g.getSellermobile());
                intent.putExtra(EMAIL, g.getSelleremail());


                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


      if (getContext() != null) {
           Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(g.getPics())).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform().placeholder(R.drawable.bshelf).error(R.drawable.userphoto)).into(holder.iv);


    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookslist.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the full error code/log here?

Answer (score 1):

Use your Activity's `Context` to load images with Glide. Pass it via the constructor of your adapter like the following.

```
// Declare a Context variable in your adapter
private Context context;

public TopAdapter(ArrayList<location> bookslist, Context context){
    this.bookslist = bookslist;
    this.context = context; // add this as a field in your adapter class.
}
```

And then use glide with the activity context.

```
Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(g.getPics())).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform().placeholder(R.drawable.bshelf).error(R.drawable.userphoto)).into(holder.iv);
```

Comment: sorry I forget to mention that I"m using fragment. I've edited my question and I'm getting same error this time as " You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed)"

Comment: @ProAcademy what is `Home` object ?  and the method `getContext()` ? where its implementation? keep things simple , pass `context` as is in your adapter constructor , if you are using fragments you can get the context from the `onAttach` call back.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment's getActivity()  is null because it not attached to your activity.
use [isAdded()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()) method to check your fragment  is currently added to its activity.